# Unable to DM (send direct message) to individual user (users) using slack api in Java

Tags: java, slack-api

I am trying to send message to an individual user using slack api in Java, but I am not able to. I tried various ways, but none helped. I am able to send messages to channels though but not to user directly.

Following is my code -

```
public void postToUsers() {

        var client = Slack.getInstance().methods();
        try {
            ChatPostMessageResponse response = Slack.getInstance().methods().chatPostMessage(r -> r
                    .token("xoxb-2850123307073-2837743345451-e3Y8y4cahtzeLAKIbjUHMMuC")
                    .channel("U02ABCGV9V")
                    .text("hello"));

            System.out.println("::::" + response.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException) {
            logger.error("No record for slack notification exists for id: " + id);
            );
        } catch (IOException | SlackApiException e) {
            logger.error("error: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            );
        }
    }
```

Instead of posting to user whose userid I copied in channel above, I see the message under app name in slack. I am not sure what's happening. Following is the response I get -

```
Message(type=message, subtype=null, team=T02R09Q9125, channel=null, user=U02QMMV6JD9, username=null, text=hello, blocks=null, attachments=null, ts=1639724593.000400, threadTs=null, intro=false, starred=false, wibblr=false, pinnedTo=null, reactions=null, botId=B02QF0PEFQE, botLink=null, displayAsBot=false, botProfile=BotProfile(id=B02QF0PEFQE, deleted=false, name=slack-notification-service, updated=1639470131, appId=A02Q72AKEFR, icons=BotProfile.Icons(image36=https://a.slack-edge.com/80588/img/plugins/app/bot_36.png, image48=https://a.slack-edge.com/80588/img/plugins/app/bot_48.png, image72=https://a.slack-edge.com/80588/img/plugins/app/service_72.png), teamId=T02R09Q9125), icons=null, file=null, files=null, upload=false, parentUserId=null, inviter=null, clientMsgId=null, comment=null, topic=null, purpose=null, edited=null, unfurlLinks=false, unfurlMedia=false, threadBroadcast=false, replies=null, replyCount=null, replyUsers=null, replyUsersCount=null, latestReply=null, subscribed=false, xFiles=null, lastRead=null, root=null, itemType=null, item=null)
```

Channel coming as null.

Following are the scopes I have given in order to see if it works, but it didn't -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One first would first have to create the conversation:
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create

And then translate from string conversation (name) to conversationId (in case not already known), then it can be addressed in a direct message. See "picking the right conversation". The API has further methods: https://api.slack.com/docs/conversations-api#methods - even if the raw API isn't the Java client, it clearly shows what may be possible, no matter the client.

Comment: reading your comment makes sense to me now, any suggestions if you could provide please? But the thing is it works for public channels and appeared to me that they are suggesting it https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending

Comment: My initial answer wasn't that correct, as there seem to be only 1 method to post.

Comment: `conversations.create` creates a new channel unlike starting a conversation as it may seen. Makes me wonder if I want to send it to ten users, would that be like creating 10 channels. Didn't see it getting created though for one, need to proceed with next step after creating it.

Comment: `conversations.create` creates a new channel and then it might be like inviting users to that channel. It really doesn't seem to be solving the problem of direct messages.